# Is $f(P_X,P_Y) \equiv 2 \max\{ P( X < Y ), P( Y < X ) \} - 1$ a valid distance measure for one dimensional distributions, & if so does it have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces, random-variables, entropy, functional-inequalities

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables over $\mathbb R$ with distributions $P_X(x)$ and $P_Y(x)$, respectively, and $x \in \mathbb R$. Is $$f(P_X,P_Y) \equiv 2 \max\{ P( X < Y ), P( Y < X ) \} - 1 $$ a valid distance measure for one dimensional distributions? If so, does it have a name?

The idea is that if $P_X$ has little or no overlap with $P_Y$, then either $P( X < Y )$ or $P( Y < X )$, the probability of one r.v. being greater than another, will be close to 1. If they overlap strongly, then $\max\{ P( X < Y ), P( Y < X )\}$ should be close to $\frac{1}{2}$.

The assumption is that $$\max\{ P( X < Y ), P( Y < X )\} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}.$$ This should be true since $P( Y < X ) = 1 - P( X < Y )$, and $\max\{ P( X < Y ), 1 - P( X < Y ) \}$ has to be at least one half for $0 \leqslant P( X < Y ) \leqslant 1$.

Then $f$ as defined above should range from zero to one, depending on the extent of overlap of $P_X(x)$ and $P_Y(x)$. I don't know how to prove this, so I'm posting it as a question here to see if there's a flaw in my argument or not :)

Comment: For this to be well-defines, you need $X,Y$ independent.

Comment: good catch! Y > X typos fixed :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added "independent" which I was indeed assuming, but had not stated or noticed the necessity of.

Comment: For continuous probabilities, $P(X<Y)+P(Y<X)=1.$

Comment: correct, I could have substituted $1 - P( X < Y )$ for $P( Y < X )$. I chose this notation consciously because it more closely matches the way I think about what's going on.

Comment: updated the max >= 1/2 assumption just now (i had the inequality sign backwards) :)

Comment: i think i was able to use this identity to prove the max >= 1/2 assumption.

Comment: I think it’s possible for $P(X<Y)=\frac12$ even if $PX\neq P_Y.$

Comment: Specifically, if $X$ and $Y$ are even then $P(X>Y)=P(-X>-Y)=P(X<Y).$

Comment: yes, I agree. That's OK, as far as my purposes go. I'm not sure how that compares to other distance measures.

Answer (score 1):

there are $X,Y$ so that $f(P_X,P_Y)=0$ while $P_X\neq P_Y.$

A random variable is $Z$ is even if $P_Z(x)=P_Z(-x).$ If $Z$ is even then, $P_Z(x)=P_{-Z}(x).$

If both $X,Y$ are even, continuous and independent, then:

$$P(X<Y)=P(-X<-Y)=P(X>Y)$$

So, $f(P_X,P_Y)=0.$

It is not hard to show there are such $X,Y$ with $P_X\neq P_Y.$

But a metric should not be zero between unequal points in your space.

Comment: Yes, that's OK though: it's a distance *measure*, not a *metric*.

Comment: The formula was constructed with this in mind: in some cases you *want* the measure to have this property. I.e., if you *only* care about the extent of overlap, not whether the two distributions are pointwise equal, then this is a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by “overlap,” but “distance” in math usually means a metric, which has a specific set of conditions. Namely: (1) $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y,$ and (2) $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z).$

Comment: One way to think of it, thinking out loud here, is analogous to equivalence classes of functions in measure theory. As you probably know, a set of functions that differ on sets of measure zero are equivalent with respect to the Lebesgue measure, for example. E.g., the Dirichlet Function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) is equivalent to the zero function. In this case, two functions are equivalent if their samples are indistinguishable from the standpoint of a binary decision boundary.

Comment: maybe it satisfies the "pseudometric" definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space#Definition). it looks like it satisfies properties 1 & 2 immediately. property 3 i'm not sure about: $d(x, z) \leqslant d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. something to think about, thanks! :)